# RelativeLayout with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi have main Linear Layout inside that I have these view with same tree ScrollView,LinearLayout and then Relative Layout ,I am trying to set Relative Layout Margin that is most child View but its Margin not doing anything,I have all of these view with are with height and width as Fill_Parent .Anyone can guide how I can solve this issue thing ?

Comment: Hi jcw thanks it solved , I was typing margin inside of eclipse android view property it was not writing inside the xml , when I go direct to xml and type margin it working fine ,i think i need to update my eclipse or need to cleanup the things .

Comment: @aftab if you have found the answer, add that as an answer here so it will be useful for future viewers.

Comment: Hi Suraj Bajaj yes I did update my Eclipse and restart is it working great now . . .there was some issue in ADT or eclipse libraries . .